# How to return current time and store it with doctrine?

Tags: php, date, doctrine-orm

I am currently creating a form and storing data in my database. I've created an Entity:

```
//... Rest of code

class CallRequested
{
//...//
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $requestTime;
//...//

public function setrequestTime(DateTime $requestTime)
    {
        $this->requestTime = $requestTime;
    }

    public function getrequestTime()
    {
        return $this->requestTime;
    }
```

And later I want to retrieve it in my form, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
 public function CallManager($data) 
        {
        $callRequested= new CallRequested;

        //...//

        $callRequested-> setRequestTime(new \DateTime($RequestTime));


        $this->$entityManager->persist($callRequested);



        $this->$entityManager->flush();
        }
```

I've tried: `$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());`

But this returns a string not a DateTime.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
```

And change this:

```
public function setrequestTime(DateTime $requestTime)
```

to this:

```
public function setrequestTime(\DateTime $requestTime)
```

Comment: Error:

Argument 1 passed to Application\Entity\CallRequested::setrequestTime() must be an instance of Application\Entity\DateTime, instance of DateTime given,

Comment: update answer with a new fix for DateTime @inespelaez

Comment: glad to help you! @inespelaez